# Mostrar uma string em um AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Bom, estou aprendendo android, não sei muito. Nessa aplicação, até o momento eu quero apenas apresentar o valor de "nome" no .setMessage do AlertDialog, e não estou sabendo como faço isso, grato desde já!

OBS: Quando rodo o app no meu aparelho, aparece
"Seu nome é:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{...}"

```
package usuario.app.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.view.*;


public class ComprasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText nome, idade,cidade;
Button enviar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compras);

    nome    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
    idade   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idade);
    cidade  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cidade);
    enviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enviar);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(ComprasActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Seu perfil");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Seu nome é:" + nome);
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                    dialogo.show();
                }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variável `nome` é do tipo `EditText`, que representa um elemento do layout.
Para aceder ao texto que esta contem é necessario chamar o método `getText()`:

```
dialogo.setMessage("Seu nome é:" + nome.getText());
```

É importante de salientar que o método `getText()` devolve o texto em forma de `charSequence` e não `String`, o que apesar de neste caso que é simples funcionar, noutros que venha a encontrar mais à frente pode já não funcionar.

Para obter o texto de um `EditText` em forma de `String`, deve utilizar:

```
nome.getText().toString()
```

Um exemplo disto seria o que o ramaral indicou, de atribuir o texto do `EditText` a uma variável do tipo `String`. Nesse caso teria mesmo de ser:

```
String nomeRecolhido = nome.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Estava para responder mas você antecipou-se. No entanto a sua resposta não está completamente correcta.

Comment: @ramaral Esquecime de algo?

Comment: Não propriamente, porque neste caso funciona. Mas o "mais correcto" seria usar `nome.getText().toString()`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. O início nunca é fácil, grato pela ajuda.

Comment: @ramaral Sim eu coloquei, mas acabei por andar para trás e retirei para ser mais simples. Mas em vários outros locais que é necessário uma `String` tem que ser da forma que indicou, uma vez que `getText` devolve um `charSequence` e não uma `String`

Comment: Pode ser mais simples mas o AP(que ainda está a aprender) ficará confuso quando usar só `getText()` ao atribuir a uma vairável do tipo String e der erro.

Comment: @ramaral Sim tem razão, posso completar a resposta com essa referência, para ajudar no futuro noutras situações semelhantes.